# The Operator $\overline{\partial} + \overline{\partial}^*$ on an Hermitian Manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, spin-geometry

Every compact Kähler manifold has a canonical $spin^c$ structure. Moreover, the associated Dirac operator is isomorphic to $\overline{\partial} + \overline{\partial}^*$, acting on $\Omega^{(0,\bullet)}$  twisted by an appropiate line bundle. When the Kähler condition is relaxed to Hermitian, what can one say about the operator $\overline{\partial} + \overline{\partial}^*$?

Comment: The operator still has the same principal symbol of the $spin^c$ Dirac operator, so it still produces the same index. However, its kernel could be different, so it no longer computes Dolbeault cohomology.